# How can I insert data between 2 nodes?

Tags: java, arraylist

don't know how to do it, I only need that, the rest of the code is ok
I have to insert a number between numbers 8 and 10

```
class arra{
private ArrayList<Integer> lista;
arra(){
    lista = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}

public void cargar(int i){
    lista.add(i);
}

public ArrayList <Integer> traer(){
    return lista;
}

public void InsertarInicio(int i){
    lista.add(0,i);
}

}
public class Trabclase {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    ArrayList<Integer> li = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    arra obj = new arra();
    int i=0;

    for(i=2;i<=10;i=i+2){
        obj.cargar(i);
    }

    li = obj.traer();
    System.out.println("lista: ");
    System.out.println(li);

    obj.cargar(14);
    System.out.println("lista adicionando el 14 al final ");
    System.out.println(li);

    System.out.println("lista adicionando un valor al inicio");
    obj.InsertarInicio(0);
    System.out.println(li);



}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do li.add(5, 9); 5 is the index number and 9 is the number that you want to add.

Comment: the number that I need to add is 8.5, so, how can I insert it? 
netbeans send me an error

Comment: You cannot add 8.5 because your ArrayList has a type of Integer. You need to change the type to be Double in order to save a number with decimals.